# Why isn't my packaged Electron app showing SVGs?

Tags: svg, electron, electron-packager

I'm using electron-packager to package my app, yet no SVGs show up in the production version compared to the development version.

The build files contain the SVGs, yet somehow they are still not showing up in my prod build.
I simply import the SVG directly and show it as an . Non-SVG images seem to be working correctly, though.

[Here's a picture of the two side-by-side.](https://gyazo.com/5a4b12adbc534bf0a3a0f5697c5c8c8f) Any ideas why this could be occurring?

This is the component you see in the screenshot.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import drop from "../../assets/images/drop.svg";
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";
import { ListContext } from "../context/ListContext";

const Start = (props) => {
    const [list, setList] = useContext(ListContext);
    const [redir, setRedir] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div
            className="start"
            onDrop={() => {
                setRedir(<Redirect to="/list" />);
            }}>
            <div className="start-drop">
                <img src={drop} draggable="false" alt="" />
                <p>Drop files or folders here to minify.</p>
            </div>
            {redir}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Start;
```

And here's the part of my package.json where I package using electron-packager:

```
"scripts": {

        ...

        "package": "yarn run build",
        "postpackage": "electron-packager ./ --out=./release --icon=assets/icons/mac.icns"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I had an extra svg loader in my webpack config that seemed to be canceling out my fileloader svg rule. All working now!